# Error displaying PDF document in C# WebApp

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, .net, visual-studio

I want to show a document generated from base64 in my web, but throws this error and doesn't display anything. There's no error in the controller, this message shows in the browser (Chrome):

```
Uncaught Error: Assertion failed
    at assert (pdf_viewer_wrapper.js:5)
    at Viewport.getPageAtY_ (pdf_viewer_wrapper.js:16)
    at Viewport.getMostVisiblePage (pdf_viewer_wrapper.js:16)
    at HTMLElement.updateUIForViewportChange (pdf_viewer_wrapper.js:2241)
    at HTMLElement.viewportChanged_ (pdf_viewer_wrapper.js:2091)
    at Viewport.viewportChangedCallback_ (pdf_viewer_wrapper.js:2091)
    at Viewport.updateViewport_ (pdf_viewer_wrapper.js:16)
    at pdf_viewer_wrapper.js:16
    at Viewport.mightZoom_ (pdf_viewer_wrapper.js:16)
    at Viewport.fitToNone (pdf_viewer_wrapper.js:16)
```

Frame for document:
`<iframe id="framePDF2" frameborder="0" style="width: 100%; height:900px;" src=""></iframe>`

JQuery to obtain base64 from controller:

```
success: function (result) {
     $('#framePDF2').attr('src', "data:application/pdf;base64," + result.pdf);
}
```

Comment: Are you sure it is a properly encoded base64 string of a PDF?

Comment: @pcisrra76, as others said, we can not know if your base64 string is correct. It will be better for you to provide the code related to how do you get the base64 string.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have an answer, but since a few weeks I have the same issue on a website in Chrome Browser (Versie 90.0.4430.212 (Officiële build) (64-bits, Windows 10) with a webpage which isn't changed and worked fine before. In Edge no problems. For me it seems to be a Chrome-bug